# Рандомное 4-х значное число в котором все элементы разные

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать что бы у меня выходило рандомное число в котором каждая цифра отличается от другой? к примеру в диапазоне от 1234 (все цифры разные, как видно) до 9870.
Спасибо.

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) чтобы получить уникальный набор цифр. Далее проверить, что этот набор цифр не начинается с `0`, и в случае чего переставить этот `0` куда либо ещё (можно просто рандомно перемешивать набор цифр до тех пор пока в начало не встанет что-либо отличное от `0`).

```
import random

def get_random_value():
    # Берём 4 уникальные случайные цифры из набора
    value = random.sample("1234567890", 4)

    # Перемешиваем последовательность до тех пор пока не будет нуля в начале 
    while value[0] == '0':
        random.shuffle(value)

    # Ну или можно просто переставить 0 в конец последовательности 
    #if value[0] == '0':
    #    value.append(value.pop(0))

    # Склеиваем последовательность в строку и преобразуем её в число
    return int(''.join(value))

print(get_random_value())
```

Если же вас устроят и трёхзначные числа (т.е. с нулём в начале), то выкиньте цикл `while`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
 
 
def rdm():
    global n
    n = random.randint(0, 9)
    return n
 
 
num = []
 
for _ in range(4):
    while rdm() in num:
        rdm()
    num.append(n)
 
for i in num:
    print(i, end='')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ